# Error while uploading image to database in php

Tags: php, mysql

The database connection is maintained well. First lets look out the code:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    # code...
    $tenant_name = $_POST['name'];
    $tenant_address = $_POST['address'];
    $tenant_contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $tenant_family = $_POST['family_member'];
    $tenant_date = $_POST['month'].$_POST['day'].$_POST['year'];

    // image 
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $target_path = "/var/www/html/records/admin/images/";
    $target_file_path = $target_path.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);




    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_file_path)){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO tenants (name, address, contact, no_of_family_member, started_date, image) VALUES ('$tenant_name', '$tenant_address', '$tenant_contact', '$tenant_family', '$tenant_date', '$file_name')";

        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if ($query) {
            # code...
            echo "New Tenant Added";
        }
        else 
            echo "Data insertion error!";
    }
    else
        echo "error uploading image";

}
```

Heres the Form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="new_tenant_process.php" method="POST">
    <table border="0">
        <tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Permanent Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="address"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Contact No.:</td><td><input type="text" name="contact"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>No of Famiy Member:</td><td><select name="family_member">
                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                            </select></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Started at:</td><td colspan="3"><select name="month">
                                    <option value="jan">Jan</option>
                                    <option value="feb">Feb</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name="day">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name="year">
                                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Upload a picture</td><td><input type="file" name="file"></td>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

When i run this piece of code:

> if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_file_path))

this condition part fails and `error uploading image` gets echoed in the browser. I might have lost the track.. Help!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get `move_uploaded_file` inside `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` condition.

You want to move file after form is sent, no earlier.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    ...
    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_file_path)){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually `move_uploaded_file` is inside the if condition. I must have miss typed here.. THe problem persists!!

Comment: In your question, `move_uploaded_file` is outside the `if (isset($_POST['submit'])` condition. If you changed it, update your question

Comment: @Avhsk: what about permissions? Is target directory writable? Are you using correct path?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your filename contain only English characters.

Check twice filename and destination folder - `$temp_name`, `$target_file_path`

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    # code...
    $tenant_name = $_POST['name'];
    $tenant_address = $_POST['address'];
    $tenant_contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $tenant_family = $_POST['family_member'];
    $tenant_date = $_POST['month'].$_POST['day'].$_POST['year'];

    // image 
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    // make sure you have something in $file_name

    $target_path = "/var/www/html/records/admin/images/";
    $target_file_path = $target_path.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

}


if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_file_path)){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tenants (name, address, contact, no_of_family_member, started_date, image) VALUES ('$tenant_name', '$tenant_address', '$tenant_contact', '$tenant_family', '$tenant_date', '$file_name')";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($query) {
        # code...
        echo "New Tenant Added";
    } else {
        echo "Data insertion error!";
        }
} else {
    echo "error uploading image";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the image folder permission:

```
chmod 755 /var/www/html/records/admin/images
```

Comment: I have full write access to the folder..The problem persists

Answer (score 0):

First thing make sure you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` added to you form. Second, you have set the `$target_path wrong`.

Try:

```
$target_path = "./images/";
if you are uploading from your admin folder.
```

Comment: and also his move upload part is outside of if statement. So he got no variable to run his query or to run the function. Thanks

Comment: did that, still same!!

Comment: All your codes are correct so the problem is definitely in the $target_path variable. For testing purpose, create a new folder named uploads inside your project folder.

Then set `$target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'<your project folder name>'.'/uploads/';`